# set the font of a custom label added on a custom dialog page in nsis installer

Tags: installation, dialog, custom-controls, nsis

how to set the font of a label added on a custom added page in nsis installer

To create the label i have used this :

```
    nsDialogs::Create 1018

var Label

${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 0 100% 32u "PLEASE CHOOSE WHAT DO YOU WANT TO INSTALL:"
Pop $Label
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
!include nsDialogs.nsh
var Label
page custom pre
function pre
nsDialogs::Create 1018

${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 0 100% 32u "PLEASE CHOOSE WHAT DO YOU WANT TO INSTALL:"
Pop $Label
CreateFont $0 "Arial" 18
SendMessage $Label ${WM_SETFONT} $0 1

nsDialogs::Show
functionend
```

Comment: thanks a lot sir, but can you also please explain me its working: CreateFont $0 "Arial" 18 ----this puts the Font detail in the variable $0 , am i right?

Comment: @sqlchild: Yes, it puts the font handle (HFONT in win32) in $0

Comment: After that what is this doing : SendMessage $Label ${WM_SETFONT} $0 1  ---what is the '1' doing at last ?

Comment: @sqlchild: All WM_* messages are documented on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632642%28v=vs.85%29.aspx