# NSIS Install like in TeamViewer (Portable mode option)

Tags: installation, nsis

What I basically want is TeamViewer-like first page for my NSIS installer with the following options:

1. 3 radio buttons for: Run Only; Install for current user; Install for all users (requires restart with admin rights).
2. A label for license like in TeamViewer (i.e. no actual EULA page, only a link to it in the footer).
3. A button that can change text, i.e. Accept and Run or Accept and Install.

I cannot figure out how to do it easily in terms of UI and in terms of control flow.

Also I need the ability to restart the installer if user decides to install program for all users (i.e. I guess there should be a detectable command line switch, so that if present installer will automatically assume 3rd install type).

A screenshot of a sample UI as requested:

[image]

A sample NSIS template would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: A screenshot would help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
...
RequestExecutionLevel user

!include LogicLib.nsh
!include nsDialogs.nsh
!include FileFunc.nsh
!include MUI2.nsh

Var mode
Var modeRadioRun
Var modeRadioInstCU
Var modeRadioInstLM

Function OnRadioChange
GetDlgItem $1 $hwndparent 1 ; Find Install/Next button
${NSD_GetState} $modeRadioRun $0
${If} $0 = ${BST_CHECKED} 
    ${NSD_SetText} $1 "Accept && Run" 
${Else}
    ${NSD_SetText} $1 "Accept && Install" 
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd

Function ModePageCreate
!insertmacro MUI_HEADER_TEXT "Welcome to blah" "blah blah"

${GetParameters} $0
ClearErrors
${GetOptions} "$0" "/ELEVATEDINSTALL" $0
${IfNot} ${Errors}
    UserInfo::GetAccountType
    Pop $0
    ${If} $0 == "Admin"
        StrCpy $mode 1
        Abort ; Skip page and start installing
    ${Else}
        MessageBox mb_iconstop "Admin rights required!"
    ${EndIf}
${EndIf}

nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $0

${NSD_CreateRadioButton} 30u 20u 50% 12u "Run"
Pop $modeRadioRun
${NSD_OnClick} $modeRadioRun OnRadioChange

${NSD_CreateRadioButton} 30u 40u 50% 12u "Install for current user"
Pop $modeRadioInstCU
${NSD_OnClick} $modeRadioInstCU OnRadioChange

${NSD_CreateRadioButton} 30u 60u 50% 12u "Install for all users"
Pop $modeRadioInstLM
${NSD_OnClick} $modeRadioInstLM OnRadioChange

${NSD_CreateLink} 20u -14u 50% 12u "License"
Pop $0
${NSD_OnClick} $0 ShowLicense

${NSD_Check} $modeRadioRun
call OnRadioChange ; Trigger button change
nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Function ModePageLeave
${NSD_GetState} $modeRadioRun $0
${NSD_GetState} $modeRadioInstCU $1
${If} $0 = ${BST_CHECKED}
    InitPluginsDir
    SetOutPath $pluginsdir
    File "myapp.exe"
    ExecWait '"$pluginsdir\myapp.exe"'
    SetOutPath $temp ; Don't lock $pluginsdir
    Quit
${ElseIf} $1 = ${BST_CHECKED}
    StrCpy $mode 0
${Else}
    StrCpy $mode 1
    UserInfo::GetAccountType
    Pop $0
    ${If} $0 != "Admin"
        ExecShell "runas" '"$exepath"' "/ELEVATEDINSTALL"
        Quit
    ${EndIf}
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd

Function ShowLicense
ExecShell "" "http://example.com/license"
FunctionEnd

Page Custom ModePageCreate ModePageLeave
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_CONFIRM
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

Section
${If} $mode > 0
    SetShellVarContext all
    StrCpy $InstDir "$ProgramFiles\MyApp"
${Else}
    SetShellVarContext current
    StrCpy $InstDir "$LocalAppData\Programs\MyApp"
${EndIf}

SetOutPath $InstDir
File myapp.exe
CreateShortcut "$SMPrograms\MyApp.lnk" "$InstDir\myapp.exe"
WriteUninstaller "$InstDir\Uninst.exe"
WriteRegStr SHCTX "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\MyAppGuid" "UninstallString" '"$InstDir\Uninst.exe"'
WriteRegStr SHCTX "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\MyAppGuid" "DisplayName" "MyApp blah blah"
SectionEnd

Section Uninstall
; Todo: Remove files and registry entries (You should write to a .ini in $InstDir so you know if it was a per user or machine install)
RMDir "$InstDir"
SectionEnd
```

You might want to edit the base UI to make the install button larger with [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) (on one of the files in NSIS\Contrib\UIs) and in the script use `ChangeUI` to apply.

Comment: Thanks so much! Exactly what I wanted!

Comment: As a quick side question, do you know how to set the font to bold for NSD_CreateLabel?

Comment: @George: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5896458 and read the documentation for the parameters to CreateFont...

Comment: Thank you! And if you have time one final thing, I want to modify a text of a custom label (which is created with NSD_CreateLabel) inside OnRadioChange function, however I cannot figure out how to get its handle using GetDlgItem

Comment: Just create a variable and store the handle there (Like I did with the radio buttons) To use GetDlgItem you first have to find the inner dialog (FindWindow in the helpfile has a example) and then figure out the id with [win]spy[++] or some other tool.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, I couldn't figure out how do I "skip forward" UI-wise (i.e. jump to "Installing" MUI page) from ModePageLeave function? I need this to show progress of unpacking of my app.

Comment: If you do nothing in the LEAVE function it will go to the next page, `Abort` can be used to stop the page change so I don't really understand what you are asking...

Comment: Thank you, Anders! I figured it out. Basically I  moved file-copy and program launch routines from ModePageLeave function into my primary install section, where I would check based on variable set in ModePageLeave whether it's a real install or "fake" one only for extracting files and launching the app. I skipped pages by using Abort inside function used by MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE. Just writing this out in case it may benefit others.